# Paint words red in a chat window (spark.components.Label or mx.controls.Text)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, label, flex4.5, textcolor

I'm trying to change the color of all 4-letter words in a [spark.components.Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html).

It is a chat-like program, where user enters words into the TextInput field, presses ENTER and the lines are **appended** to the Label (or Text or TextArea or RichText - whatever is suitable here).

I have prepared this simple test case below, it will run instantly in your Flash Build 4.6 and the code to find the words and their indices is already there.

My problem is to figure out how to change the color of text parts programmatically (i.e. by ActionScript 3) and repeatedly, I just can't figure it out despite [reading the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-8000.html) again and again.

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

**Test.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    minWidth="400" minHeight="300">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private const WORD:RegExp = /\b[a-z]{4}\b/i; 

            public function chat(event:FlexEvent):void {
                var line:String = _input.text;
                var start:int = 0;

                do {
                    var rest:String = line.substr(start);
                    var found:int = rest.search(WORD);
                    // no more 4-letter words found
                    if (found < 0)
                        break;
                    var word:String = rest.substr(found, 4);
                    trace('word=' + word + ' @ index=' + (start + found));
                    start += found + 4;
                } while (start + 4 <= line.length);

                _output.text += (line + "\n"); 
                _input.text = '';
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="_output" left="4" top="4" right="4" bottom="24" backgroundColor="0xFFFFCC" />
    <s:TextInput id="_input" bottom="4" right="4" enter="chat(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

**UPDATE:** I'm trying RichText + the code below as suggested by Georgi and see that the pattern replacement has worked (by looking at the **trace()** output), but get the error:

*TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "[object TextFlow][object TextFlow]" to flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    minWidth="400" minHeight="300">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;

            private const WORD:RegExp = /\b[a-z]{4}\b/ig; 

            public function chat(event:FlexEvent):void {
                var line:String = _input.text.replace(WORD, '<font color="#FF0000">$&</font>') + '<br>';
                trace('line=' + line);
                // XXX how to append text here? XXX
                _output.textFlow += TextConverter.importToFlow(line, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT); 
                _input.text = '';
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:RichText id="_output" left="4" top="4" right="4" bottom="24" />
    <s:TextInput id="_input" bottom="4" right="4" enter="chat(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

**UPDATE 2:** If I use **_output.textFlow =** above then the TypeError goes away. But I need to **append** the text somehow...

Comment: You have a several problems in the updated code - arithmetic on textFlow (use "=" instead of "+="), wrong pattern in replace ("$&") and your regex is missing the "g" flag. Read my sample carefully one more time. :)

Comment: 1) I'm using "+=" because I need to append text, not replace it. 2) the "$&" is correct too - it matches the entire pattern and then the capturing brackets aren't needed. I can verify it by looking at trace() output, the string is replaced okay 3) any suggestions about the TypeError please?

Comment: The TypeError is caused by the "+=". With this operator you are not appending anything - importToFlow is creating a TextFlow object, not a String. Actually, in this code, you are not supposed to touch the text in the _output component directly. The full text is kept in a variable (in my example it's called "output") every time it's changed, we are creating a corresponding TextFlow object. You can think of TextFlow objects as wrappers around the HTML. Try reading the docs for TextFlow or running my example without modifications.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the update. The "output" variable contains the HTML formatted text from the beggining - everything that the user sees in the RichText component. That's why I append the line every time with "+=". Then I get this variable and create a TextFlow for it (the whole HTML). As I said, try running my (actually working) example without modifications and with some trace() expressions or breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with a `s:Label` component. You may try using `s:RichText` (which, luckily, isn't very different from `s:Label`) with appropriate HTML formatting. You'll have to keep the produced HTML and set the `textFlow` every time, by using `TextConverter` first. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
   xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
   minWidth="400" minHeight="300">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private const WORD:RegExp = /\b([a-z]{4})\b/ig; 

        private var output:String = "";

        public function chat(event:FlexEvent):void {                
            output += _input.text.replace(WORD, '<font color="0xFF0000">$1</font>') + '<br>';

            _output.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(output, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);

            _input.text = "";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

    <s:RichText id="_output" left="4" top="4" right="4" bottom="24" backgroundColor="0xFFFFCC" />
    <s:TextInput id="_input" bottom="4" right="4" enter="chat(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

The code above is not working perfectly, but seems enough to demonstrate the concept.

Edit:
Note the "g" flag in the regex to match **all** the four-letter words.

Comment: Thank you, but I get a TypeError - please see my updated question